# Intellij not detecting runConfigurations xml

Tags: intellij-idea, import, run-configuration

I imported a simple sbt scala project in Intellij idea.
Once the project is imported, I create runConfigurations directory inside .idea directory and moved all the checked in runConfigurations inside 
.idea/runConfigurations.
Still I am not able to see anu run configurations.

Comment: Try closing the project and importing it again now with run configurations already in place

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion worked. I thought it will work automatically without reopening.

Comment: actually it was always working by just leaving and giving focus on intellij. nowadays not even a restart with invalidating caches helps :-(

Answer (score 0):

After you have imported the .run/****.xml file in the project folder, close the PyCharm project and reopen it.